# Escapes special character in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have control with `id='#ul_[]ER$%#'` but when I used following regex syntax to escape special character in control id then it return the following string `#ul_\[\]\E\R\$\%\#`,
It escapes the alphabets also. How can I only escape the special character in string using jQuery. To escape the special character I used following regular expression:

```
$("#ul_"+data.replace(/([#;&,.+-_=?{}*~\':%"!^$[\]()=>|\/])/g,"\\$1"))
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) might help you

Comment: I already tried this.If any special character in between character then its not working.e.g. $%H&K

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked and answered, more developments have been made in the DOM and CSSOM space to make this easier. I present [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape):

```js
var data = '[]ER$%#';

var sel = '#' + CSS.escape("#ul_"+data);

console.log($(sel).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#ul_[]ER$%#'>test</div>
```

No regular expressions needed. Guaranteed (by your browser vendor) proper escaping.

<sub>Not really guaranteed at all. Use at your own risk.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. The `-` inside the regular expression class ( `[...]` ) is not taken as a literal hyphen, but delimits a range from `+` to `_`, which includes upper case alphanumerical characters. So either escape that hyphen, or place it at the end of the class;
2. A selector by `id` attribute should start with a `#`. Although your `id` attribute value starts itself with a hash (`#`), you need another one, and you need to escape the one that is part of the `id` value.

So this will work:

```js
var data = '[]ER$%#';

var sel = '#' + ("#ul_"+data).replace(/([#;&,.+\-_=?{}*~\':%"!^$[\]()=>|\/])/g,"\\$1");

console.log($(sel).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#ul_[]ER$%#'>test</div>
```

Some more comments:

- You could probably just remove the `-` and `_` from the list of characters to escape. They have no special meaning in jQuery selectors.
- On the other hand, the space, `` ` `` (back tick), `@` and `<` *should* be escaped. See the list of characters in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped

Answer (score 0):

There is a function described here that may work for you:

https://totaldev.com/escaping-characters-to-get-a-valid-jquery-id/

```
function jqSelector(str) {
    return str.replace(/([;&,\.\+\*\~':"\!\^#$%@\[\]\(\)=>\|])/g, '\\$1');
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$('#'+jqSelector('id.with,special#characters')).text('My Selected Element');
```